# how do you dump a connection inside a node.js SNICallback?

Tags: node.js

TLDR; how do you dump a connection inside a node.js SNICallback?

I'd just like to know what is the official way to say (from the callback), "No soup for you".

All that the [official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener) say is:

> SNICallback(servername, cb)  A function that will be called if the client supports SNI TLS extension. Two arguments will be passed when called: servername and cb. SNICallback should invoke cb(null, ctx), where ctx is a SecureContext instance. (tls.createSecureContext(...) can be used to get a proper SecureContext.) If SNICallback wasn't provided the default callback with high-level API will be used (see below).

unfortunately, when you do "look below" there is nothing of relevance to "see below" other than some example code that doesn't even set SNICallback in options.

**Main Question** (as originally asked before clarification edits and the above excerpt from docs):

I've a server that does dynamic ssl certs (for a lib i am developing for lets encrypt based rollouts). i had a situation where i needed to add some validation because somehow someone tried hitting the server with a different domain name than one i was expecting. i've modded the code to stop it actually crashing the server, but i'm wondering what's the prescribed way to deal with wanting to forcibly dump a connection if this sort of thing happens. in the meantime i am returning undefined (or passing that to the callback if it's invoked using that parlance (there was an update to the TLS libs a while back where a callback was added, so i'm using a null test on the cb to decide how to return the context)

**UPDATE**: 
As per @robertklep's suggestion i have updated my code to send/return an Error object, and will wait and see how that fares in the big wide world. i'd just like to know that error is not stringified and sent to the remote connection as it just gives more information exposing an attack vector, if indeded it is someone trying their luck. (Error has a stack trace giving a lot of information about the internal structure of a app, so you don't really want that going out over a network connection). since i am not sure how to duplicate the conditions that allowed a hostname to be sent to the server that has a different ip than the one pointed to by the requested host. (other than registering a domain name and tricking a browser into hitting the wrong ip). I suppose it could be done by requesting a TLS upgrade from an http request. i can a have a look at that. one of the things i do when i spin up the server is double check the domain name is actually pointing at the local machine, and so i am fairly confident that the domains it is serving are correct. it follows therefore that any domain name that isn't in the prescribed list has been spoofed.

**Updated source**: (after the suggestion)

```
var SNICallback= function (domain,cb) {
                        var check_domain=secure_db.domains[domain];
                        if (check_domain===undefined) {
                            runtime.console.log("warning - attempt to access domain:",domain);
                            var err=new Error(domain+" is not here.");
                            return cb ? cb(err,undefined) : err;
                        } else { 
                            var ctx=check_domain.context;
                            return cb ? cb(undefined,ctx) : ctx;
                        }
                    }
```

**Original Fix**: (before the suggestion)

```
var SNICallback = function (domain,cb) {
                        var check_domain=secure_db.domains[domain];
                        if (check_domain===undefined) {
                            runtime.console.log("warning - attempt to access domain:",domain);
                            return cb ? cb(undefined,undefined) : undefined;
                        } else {
                            var ctx=check_domain.context;
                            return cb ? cb(undefined,ctx) : ctx;
                        }
                    };
```

**Original** (buggy version):

```
var SNICallback = function (domain,cb) {
                        var ctx=secure_db.domains[domain].context;
                        return cb ? cb(undefined,ctx) : ctx;
                    };
```

Comment: i'm probably going to change that test to an explicit `typeof cb==='function' ?` but at the moment the falsy ? test is working adeqately

Comment: I don't know about older Node versions, but when you get a callback argument, did you try passing an error as first argument in the case where you want to drop the connection?

Comment: @robertklep i would, but as i'm not sure how to duplicate the event that triggered the condition (some external hacker or bot just randomly hit the server) i  can't test to see what happens. i'm not sure how you get a standard browser to send a malformed request to a host with an incorrect domain name. it's something most browser developers try to avoid at all costs. if we were talking standard http, sure you'd use telnet. but this is in the TLS negotiation phase. it does make sense though, i will change my code, and wait and see if it pops up again.

Comment: You can always perform a test that will _always_ return an error (which I did, cURL returns `Server aborted the SSL handshake`).